# Array contained within JS Object is nested two-deep

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am building an array of objects. The structure should be like this:

```
var array = [
 { 'keyword' : 'somekeyword',
   'guidelines' : [ "guideline1", "guideline2", "guideline3"] 
 },
 { 'keyword' : 'anotherkeyword',
   'guidelines' : [ "guideline1", "guideline2", "guideline3"] 
 }
]
```

Instead, it's like this:

```
var array = [
 { 'keyword' : 'somekeyword',
   'guidelines' : [[ "guideline1", "guideline2", "guideline3"]] 
 },
 { 'keyword' : 'anotherkeyword',
   'guidelines' : [[ "guideline1", "guideline2", "guideline3"]] 
 }
]
```

What I am doing wrong in building my objects to get that second level of nesting on the guidelines array? This is the function that builds the array, reading in from a table of data in a HTML file:

```
    $(html).find('tr').each(function() {
                keywordObj = {};
                guidelinesCell;
                $(this).find('td').each(function() {
                    cellClass= $(this).attr('class');
                    if (cellClass === 's2') {
                        keywordObj.keyword = $(this).text();
                    } else if (cellClass === 's3' || cellClass == 's4') {
                        guidelinesCell = [];
                        guidelinesCell.push( $(this).html().split('<br>') );
                        //Possibly it's this push that's causing the problem?

                        keywordObj.guidelines = guidelinesCell;

                        console.log(guidelinesCell) 
                        console.log(keywordObj.guidelines)

                        //At this point, the array is already nested- the console logs return eg                                                                   
                             [Array[2]]
                              0: Array[2]
                                 0: "GuidelineName1.pdf"
                                 1: "GuidelineName2.pdf"
                    }
                });
                i ++;

                if (keywordObj.guidelines && keywordObj.guidelines[0].length > 1) {

                    keywordsToLeitlinien.push(keywordObj);
                }

            });
```

For reference, here's a sample of the mark-up it's reading from:

```
 <tr dir="ltr">
     <td class="hd">
        <p style="height:39px;">.</p>
     </td>
     <td dir="ltr" class="s2">samplekeyword</td>
     <td dir="ltr" class="s4">GuidelineName.pdf <br>GuidelineName.pdf</td>
 </tr>
```

---

EDIT to add:

This isn't a problem in my processing within this file, but I am outputting this array to a JSON file eventually, and I would rather solve the problem than keep having to work around this sort of output:

```
{"keyword":"keywordname","guidelines":[["guidelineName1 ","guidelineName2"]]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `split` returns an array here:

```
$(this).html().split('<br>')
```

And since you are pushing this array into another array, it will become nested.

Instead, try something like:

```
guidelinesCell = $(this).html().split('<br>')
```

Comment: You're right, and you get the tick (when I am allowed to accept an answer) for being the fastest correct answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
guidelinesCell.push( $(this).html().split('<br>') );
```

`.split` will return an array, so it's essentially the same as pushing an array into another array.

So just assign guidelinesCell to the result of split instead

```
guidelinesCell = $(this).html().split('<br>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I do think push is the problem as the jQuery function returns an array. Try pushing only the first element:

```
   guidelinesCell.push( $(this).html().split('<br>')[0] );
                        //Possibly it's this push that's causing the problem?
```

Answer (score 0):

`.split` splits a string into an array.  `.push` is an operation to add an element to an array.  So what you have is `[]` and you are pushing `["guideline values"]` onto it creating the nesting.

What you should use instead of `.push` is [`.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)